# Select specific data in Django query and map the result (between th and td) in a table

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I've been avoiding this way too many times and I think it's time to ask for some help.

First of all, I have the following structure of the relevant parts of my project:

```
# models.py

class LocationsProvisioning(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dates = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    locations = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    goods = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantities = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    samples = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

```
# forms.py

DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {
    'class': 'datepicker form-control',
    'name': 'dates'})

class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(label="Start date", required=True,
                                 widget=DateInput(),
                                 initial=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
    end_date = forms.DateField(label="End date", required=True,
                               widget=DateInput(),
                               initial=datetime.date.today())
    locations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Select some locations',
                                               queryset=LocationsModel.objects.all().order_by('name'), required=True,
                                               widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
                                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                                   'name': 'locations'
                                               }))
```

```
# views.py

def reports_view(request):
    form = ReportForm(request.POST or None)
    selected_locations = ''

    all_goods = GoodsModel.objects.all().order_by('name')

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            start_date = str(form.cleaned_data.get('start_date'))
            end_date = str(form.cleaned_data.get('end_date'))
            selected_locations = form.cleaned_data.get('locations')

        else:
            form = ReportForm()

    return render(request, 'admin/coffee_app/raport.html', {
        'form': form,
        'selected_locations': selected_locations,
        'all_goods': all_goods  # those will be the headers of the table
    })
```

So far so good, I have in my template a table which contains as headers, `goods`, and as the first column the `selected_locations`.

The html looks like this (*I've removed some html tags for readability*):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    {{ form.start_date.label_tag }}
    {{ form.end_date.label_tag }}
    {{ form.locations }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn my-btn" />
</form>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Locations</th>
        {% for good in all_goods %}
            <th>{{ good }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        <th>Samples</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for location in selected_locations %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ location }}</td>
            <td>{{ here_I_should_have_quantities (some kind of map between the selected location and the `good` }}</td>   
            <td>{{ here_I_should_have_probes_for_selected_locations }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I'd like to do some kind of select (`LocationsProvisioning.objects.filter()`) which should look like:

```
SELECT quantities, samples 
FROM LocationsProvisioning 
WHERE locations in selected_locations and dates BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

I know I can do something like:

```
LocationsProvisioning.objects.filter(dates__range=[start_date, end_date])
```

but I can't seem to find a way to do: `SELECT quantities, samples FROM LocationsProvisioning WHERE locations in selected_locations`

What looks impossible to me, is also match the quantities / probes only where needed:

```
            Good_1 Good_2 Good_3 Good_4 Samples
locality_1    23            2      7       3
locality_2           3      40     7       5     
locality_3     1     2                     3
```

More details:

- each `selected_locality` has a `sample`
- a `selected_locality` might not have a value for all `goods` (see the above table)

*PS: I couldn't find a better title for this, so feel free to edit it*

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized that wouldn't work for your case. Your SQL example only has 2 conditions; location and date, shouldn't there be 3 conditions? How do you know which quantity belongs to which goods?

Comment: @almostabeginner that's the problem. In `LocationsProvisioning` I have the `goods` column which contain some `goods`. As a header, I have `all_goods`. I have to somehow map their names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should dates be a CharField or DateField? Try this queryset to get the data.

```
LocationsProvisioning.objects
    .filter(locations__in=selected_locations, dates__range=(start_date, end_date))
    .values('quantities','samples')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One small question: how do I access the data in the template ? I doesn't look like it's working

Comment: What does the queryset return? Try doing it in shell to find out.

Comment: The problem seems to be the `locations__in=selected_locations` because if I remove it, it returns what it should. I think that `locations` is a list of locations and when we do the `__in` it returns null. How can we specify `for each_location in locations: LocationsProvisioning.objects.filter(each_location__in=...)` ?

Comment: @Dex'ter Can you run this query and let me know what the result is: `LocationsProvisioning.objects.all()[0].locations`.